# How to plot 1d C array as surface in python

Tags: python, c, plot, surface

Say I have a one-dimensional array of size NxN in C which I think of as a two-dimensional array, i.e. every N entries, a new row begins.

I would like to visualise this array by laying it onto a plane and then treating every entry as the height of the array above the plane, thereby creating a surface.

How would I go about transferring the data from C to Python in such a way that Python can read it in as a two-dimensional array and then plot it in three dimensions?

---

### Update

Writing the data to a CSV file, as suggested in barny's answer and by joao in the comments, worked well:

```
FILE *datafile = fopen("data.csv", "w");
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        fprintf(datafile, "%g, ", data[i * N + j]);
    }
    fprintf(datafile, "\n");
}
```

Reading it into a list in python was easy too:

```
import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open("data.csv")))
```

Unfortunately, outputting this data into a surface plot is causing problems. My python script reads

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open("data.csv")))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/len(data))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = np.array(data).reshape(Y.size,X.size)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data)

plt.show
```

If I try to run it, I get an error on line 12 (`data = np.array(data).reshape(Y.size,X.size)`
) saying `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`. I tried `np.sqrt(len(data))` instead of `len(data)` as well `256`which happens to be the value of N in my case. However, the error persisted in every case.

---

### Update 2

What finally worked for me was the suggestion by Emilie to simply write the C array out linearly, i.e.

```
FILE *datafile = fopen("data.dat", "w");
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    fwrite(&array[i * N + j], sizeof(double), 1, datafile);
}
```

and then read it in via

```
data = np.fromfile('data.dat', dtype=float, count=-1, sep='')
```

in Python followed by

```
array = data.reshape((np.sqrt(len(data)), np.sqrt(len(data))))
```

to give the array its required shape. (Note: This step will likely cause problems if your array length is not a square number.)

The complete working plotting script is

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.fromfile('data.dat', dtype=float, count=-1, sep='')

array = data.reshape((np.sqrt(len(data)), np.sqrt(len(data))))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
x = y = np.arange(0, 1, 1.0/np.sqrt(len(data)))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
array = np.array(data)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, array)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The question is quite vague, but here is one option - in your C program save the array into a csv file (xml, json, or whatever open format you prefer). In your python code read the file and then plot it.

Comment: "transferring the data from C to Python" -- you likely have some constraints here that are not explicit.  Can you just write the values to a file in C and read them back in python?

Comment: @BrianCain Not really. I actually thought about including in my question that writing the data into a file and reading it back in python would be the preferred method.

Comment: @Casimir, yes, far and away it's the simplest IMO.  There's some simple text formats like `json` that python handles well.  Otherwise you can write integers or floats in your machine's representation and read them back into python using the `struct` module.

Comment: Also swig (http://www.swig.org/) can be used to interface python and C/C++ modules, bit the file approach is surely simpler.

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: @barny Forgot to mention: line 12 at `data = np.array(data).reshape(Y.size,X.size)`.

Comment: Ah, well if you'd used my C to generate some python, the array would have been the right shape. Pretty hackish though ;-)

Comment: Ah yes as @Emilien says, it is already the right shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reshape error yields because when you read the csv, your `data` is already a list of lists, which you can simply transform to a numpy array with `np.array(data)`.

For instance if I have this file:

```
/tmp$ cat foo.csv 
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

I can do:

```
>>> import csv
>>> data = list(csv.reader(open("foo.csv")))
>>> data
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6']]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(data)
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Depending on what you want to do with this numpy array, you may also need to change the types of the elements. You could also write your data linearly and then use np.reshape. I'm not sure csv is the most elegant way of doing this, but probably a simple solution.

Comment: I'll look into `np.reshape`. However, I don' think it is correctly shaped. If I remove `.reshape(Y.size,X.size)`, I get an error on line 14, i.e. where I write the plot command, saying `ValueError: shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 1.`.

Comment: Wow! Writing the array out linearly and using `numpy.reshape` worked immediately. I'm a beginner with python and didn't know about this. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You could print the data as a python expression like this:

```
printf( "data2d = [\n" );
for ( y = 0; y < N ; y++ ) {
    printf( "  [" );
    for ( x = 0 ; x < n ; x++ ) {
        printf( " %d,", datalist[y*N+x] );
    }
    printf( " ],\n" );
}
printf( "]\n" );
```

Haven't tested this, while since I did any C, but it will be something like that.

(I don't think the trailing commas will matter - if they do, don't print them on the last entries of each row)

Or, perhaps easier, print it as a plain csv file - each line a row of the array with , between the values, then use the csv module to read it.

HTH
Barny

Comment: This is way too hackish, code and data should be separated if possible, here they clearly can be.